# Forcing subdomain Cookieless

Tags: .htaccess, cookies, google-analytics

When doing website speed tests, I often see a comment along the lines of:

> Serve static content from a cookieless domain

**I want to ensure that data served from the `static` domain - files with extension JS, SVG, PNG, JPG and CSS - do not set cookies.**

Here is a portion of my `.htaccess`:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|svg|png|jpg|css)$">
    <IfModule header_module>
        Header unset Cookie
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I set a CNAME entry for `static.example.com` with the record `www.example.com`.

How can I ensure that either all files served from the subdomain, or any files with those extensions, don't set cookies?